# Should I use Dropbox or Aperture to back up iPhone photos?

Tags: iphone, backup, photos, dropbox

I want to back up my iPhone 4 photos and have been just downloading them into Aperture and then deleting them from my phone. No desire to do any of the various sharing options, I just want to make sure I keep a copy of the photos in a safe place. Would it be better to use Dropbox? I'm thinking I need to choose one or the other.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a copy-then-delete-originals isn't a *backup*, it's just moving the files.

Comment: Right. I can't keep them all on my iPhone. But the only advantage I see with Dropbox is that it automatically puts them on my computer versus me doing the same thing manually into Aperature? I also have an external HD where they get copied.

Comment: Watch your usage with Dropbox. Those iPhone pictures can be large, and they could foreseeably, burn your service.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your Photostream set up in Aperture and on your iPhone, the photos will also get automatically downloaded to your computer. Dropbox has a similar feature, so if you wanted automatic backups, you could set up both Photostream and Dropbox sync and then back up your Aperture library (from Photostream) to your external HD. That way you have three copies, one of which you cannot modify from your phone.